# Algolia Add to nested array

Tags: c#, arrays, algolia

```
 {"EmailAddress": "matthew.harris@patheer.com",  
    "CompanyName": "Patheer",
    "Image": "user/img/matthew.harrispatheer.commatthew2.jpg",
    "FirstName": "Matthew",
    "LastName": "Harris",
    "JobFunction": "Information Technology",
    "PatheerJobsID": "B5PL0YqCeEe7np2j50h5Q",
    "JobTitle": "Database Administrator",
    "Aspirations": [
    {
      "PatheerJobsID": "685a215b4b0f418dbbf9285b28377c21",
      "JobTitle": "Data Scientist",
      "JobFunction": "Information Technology"
    }],
    "Skills": [
    {
      "SkillID": "2vRdiqCOE2XBDS3nsS1LA",
      "SkillName": "SQL",
      "SkillRating": 3
    },
    {
      "SkillID": "WEPMtg3JkU2xlpmgmvkYQ",
      "SkillName": "Accounting",
      "SkillRating": 4
    },
    {
      "SkillID": "d9c514035a554a5d8d99c411e43b683d",
      "SkillName": "Leadership",
      "SkillRating": 4
    },
    {
      "SkillID": "p2Aljae1EK3VDpx25dTKw",
      "SkillName": "MongoDB",
      "SkillRating": 3
    },
    {
      "SkillID": "c8fc21d83ea94842a8ae416df9317305",
      "SkillName": "Business Development",
      "SkillRating": 4
    },
    {
      "SkillID": "8f0a439029784e4e827e343e7f9034b2",
      "SkillName": "GAAP",
      "SkillRating": 3
    }],
    "objectID": "0157be4b-3426-4854-95b5-88e39cbc2403"
}
```

So above is my JSON and I am trying to add to the Skills array. Here is my code. What is wrong with it? I am using C# ..... and below is my function to "try" to add to the array but it doesn't work. The main function according to the Algolia website is "AddUnique", here is the link, but I am a little lost https://www.algolia.com/doc/csharp#update-an-existing-object-in-the-index

```
string algoliakey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AlgoliaKey"];
    string algoliasecret = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AlgoliaSecret"];
    AlgoliaClient client = new AlgoliaClient(algoliakey,algoliasecret);
    var index = client.InitIndex("People");
    string objectID = personid;

    StringBuilder updatealgolia = new StringBuilder();

    updatealgolia.Append("{\"Skills\": {\"SkillID\":\"" + skillid + "\", \"SkillName\":\"" + skillname + "\", \"SkillRating\":5, \"_operation\": \"AddUnique\"}, \"objectID\":\"" + objectID + "\"}");

    index.PartialUpdateObject(JObject.Parse(updatealgolia.ToString()), false);
```

Comment: what are you getting instead of what you want?  What have you tried so far?  Also String.Format is your friend.

Comment: I get an error: Algolia.Search.AlgoliaException: Missing value for the operation near line:1 column:116

I can get it to work If make it an array, but then it just overrides the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's totatlly doable.

However, you're not using the correct syntax for that. The skill element that you want to add must be in the `value` field as shown in the [C# client documentation](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-csharp#update-an-existing-object-in-the-index).

In your case, you simply need to reformat your JSON like that:

```
{
  "objectID": "<OBJECT_ID>",
  "Skills": {
    "_operation": "AddUnique",
    "value": {
      "SkillID": "<SKILL_ID>",
      "SkillName": "<SKILL_NAME>",
      "SkillRating": <SKILL_RATING>
    }
  }
}
```